# Differences between traditional packages com.day.cq.workflow and com.adobe.granite.workflow

Tags: aem

As I understand it, Granite is Adobe's name for the combination of Felix, Sling and CRX as a base platform. I am currently looking into CQ workflows, especially into developing a custom `WorkflowProcess`. I noticed that among others there are two seemingly equivalent packages, `com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec` [(Package Overview)](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/workflow/exec/package-summary.html) and `com.day.cq.workflow.exec` [(Package Overview)](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/workflow/exec/package-summary.html).

I see that deprecated classes (e.g. `JavaProcess`) have been removed and new ones have been added (e.g. `InboxItem`) while others seem to have stayed the same (e.g. `WorkflowProcess`). Whose package's `WorkflowProcess` interface should my custom `WorkflowProcess` class implement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Adobe Granite Workflow API*, introduced in AEM 5.6, is a replacement for the classic *Day Communique 5 Workflow API*. All new workflows [should use the new API](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html#Workflow%20Java%20API), but even in the AEM 6 there are some processes that still relies on the legacy API.

In the recent AEM versions both APIs are supported. For instance, in the *Process step* dialog, where you can list all `WorkflowProcess`es, you'll see services implementing both the new and the old version of the interface. Nevertheless, to be sure that your code will be compatible with the future versions of AEM, you should use the new API.

Once you decide to use CQ or Granite API, it's important to stick to your choice, as you can't mix types  from the first and the second API in one class and you shouldn't do it in one application.